# Using preg_replace to add text into line?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here's sample lines I'm working with:

```
<br/>
About Company Name<br/>
<p>This is just some random text About nothing.</p>
<br/>
```

Basically I want to manipulate any line that begins with `About` and ends with `<br/>`.

I just want to bold it like this:  `<b>About Company Name</b><br/>`

I can find that text like this:

```
^About.*<br/>
```

But I can't figure out how to add the bold symbols.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe just `preg_replace('~^(About.*)(<br\s*/>\s*)$~m', '<p>$1</p>$2', $s)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a capture group to your regex like this:

```
^(About.*)<br\/>$
```

And then use the regex like this:

```
$s = preg_replace('/^(About.*)<br\/>$/m', '<b>$1</b><br/>', $s);
```

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/iP0vK5/2)